# Maven can't find some resources on multi-module integration test classpath

Tags: java, xml, maven, module

I'm working on a multi-module maven Java EE project. We use Spring with separate configurations for each module. We have integration tests placed in the src/test/integration folder along with the UT for the respective module (lets say in src/test/ut).

When executing integration tests for module B we need to perform some clean-up/initialization first for module A on which module B depends. That translates to: we need access to the test data of module A while executing tests for module B. I set up a dependency for module B integration tests on the integration tests for module A with scope="test". The module-A-test.jar is then build and deployed in the local repository.

When the tests for module B are executed the test runner is initializaed and application-context.xml for both modules is found on the classpath. Please note that the application-context.xml for module A resides in the module-A-test.jar, so the jar is on the class path.

The structure of the module-A-test.jar is:

```
module-A-test.jar
  |- sqlFile
  |    |-clean-module-A.sql
  |    |-some other sql scripts
  |-module-A-db.properties  
  |-module-A-db-config.xml
  |-module-A-IT-config.xml
```

The structure of target folder of module-B is:

```
classes
  |- all module clases as expected
surefire-reports
  |- test result reports 
test-classes
  |- test classes 
  |- sqlFile
  |    |-clean-module-B.sql
  |    |-some more sql scripts
  |-module-B-db.properties  
  |-module-B-db-config.xml
  |-module-B-IT-config.xml
```

I read that maven test lifecycle classpath is build from these sources:

```
  - The test-classes directory
  - The classes directory
  - The project dependencies
  - Additional classpath elements
```

From that I'd expect to be able to read clean-module-A.sql and clean-module-B.sql.
Nevertheless when I run the code fragment bellow the file is not found (even for module B) and I jump out wihth ITException. Same of course for clean-module-A.sql.

```
    StringBuilder path = new StringBuilder();
    path.append("sqlFile/");
    path.append("clean-module-B.sql");
    File file = new File(path.toString());
    if (!file.exists()) {
        throw new ITException("File " + file.getPath().toString() + " does not exist");
    }
```

I hope I describd the situation correctly and clearly.

Now finally the question:
Why I'm able to see module-B-IT-config.xml (and even module-A-IT-config.xml) on the claspath but not the sql resources?

Thanks a lot for any idea about it!

Pavlin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you have is that the files you are looking for are inside jars (when you run tests from your IDE the files are directly on the file system).

Spring is loading application context files by looking in the classpath and opening a stream to read them.

You just have to do the same. i.e. something like this:

```
ModuleATestClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/sqlFile/clean-module-A.sql")
```